# Good Evening vs Good Night

Tags: phrase-choice

While leaving office at 6pm, I wonder if I shall say '**good evening**' or '**good night**' to my boss.
Since night is far off, '**good night**' sounds odd. But then,  '**good evening**' has a welcoming tone to it, as if I am entering office and not leaving.

Comment: Normally, you would say good evening when you greet someone at night, and good night when you leave them at night. Good evening is also used as a dismissal.

Comment: Use "good evening". While it is the end of the work day, there are still things to do (drive home, eat dinner, watch TV, take a bath, ???) before going to sleep. "good night" is better when you are done doing other things for the day. If you went to a party after work, and it ended at 10PM, it would be more likely to use "good night".

Comment: If you feel comfortable with neither, "See you tomorrow" also works. But I'll cast another vote for "good evening."

Comment: @user3169- I liked your question marks.:)

Answer (score 3):

Since you've mentioned that it's only 6pm then "**[Good evening](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/good-evening)**" is your choice, it means "**expressing good wishes on meeting or parting during the evening.**". However, "**good evening**" by itself is considered more of a greeting rather than a farewell so I recommend saying "**Have a good evening**" instead.

You could also say something like "**Goodbye and good evening to you**".

We usually say "**[Good night](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/good-night?s=t)**" when the time is for a normal person to sleep, like 9-6pm for instance. "**Good night**" often means "**I'm off to bed**"; it's "**an expression of farewell used in parting at nighttime or when going to sleep**". However, you wouldn't use that phrase in the daylight.

Comment: Could you provide contemporary examples with *good evening* in which the sense of *farewell* is clear?

Comment: @userr2684291 Unfortunately, only "**Have a good evening**" is practically used a farewell. I'm unaware though whether you can say "**good afternoon**" to say goodbye after 6pm.